# DoubleClick event on QTreeView has no result when trying to capture mouse position

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreeview

I am working with Python 3.6 and pyqt 4.11. I have two QTreeViews stacked in a Widget, both of them display some batch jobs so each step can expand to show all functions. I want to be able to double click on one line of the tree view and generate a pop up dialogue  where I can edit the parameters of the function I double clicked on.

If I connect the double click signal without capturing the position:

```
self.connect(self.QTreeView, QtCore.SIGNAL('mouseDoubleClickEvent()'),print('OK'))
```

it works and OK is printed.

However as soon as I try to catch the cursor position nothing happens anymore. I have tried both to connect the whole widget and the treeView to a simple test function. It doesn't work at all, not even OK gets printed.

```
self.connect(self.QTreeView, QtCore.SIGNAL('mouseDoubleClickEvent(const QPoint &)'),self.showDlg)

def showDlg (self, point):
        print ('OK')
        treeidx=self.treeview.indexAt(point)
        print (treeidx)
```

A ContextMenu is triggered by right click on the whole Widget and it works

```
self.QTreeWidget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)   

self.connect(self.QTreeWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)'), self.customMyContextMenu)
```

But double clicking on the same Widget gives no result

```
self.connect(self.QTreeWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('mouseDoubleClickEvent(const QPoint &)'),self.showDlg)
```

I would like to use the pointer position to know in what leaf of the tree view  the changes have to happen, I thought
`treeview.indexAt(point)`
would be the way to do that, but since my simple function doesn't get called at all, there must be some other problem I don't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it strange that in your first code is printed "OK", what returns to me is an error because connect also expects a callable, but print('OK') returns None that is not a callable. Besides, `mouseDoubleClickEvent` is not a signal but an event which reaffirms my strangeness.

Instead you have to use the `doubleClicked` signal that returns the `QModelIndex` associated with the item, and to get the position you have to use the `QCursor::pos()` next to `mapFromGlobal()` of the `viewport()` of `QTreeView`. You must also use the new connection syntax.

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


def create_model(parent):
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent)
    for i in range(3):
        parent_item = QtGui.QStandardItem("Family {}".format(i))
        for j in range(3):
            child1 = QtGui.QStandardItem("Child {}".format(i * 3 + j))
            child2 = QtGui.QStandardItem("row: {}, col: {}".format(i, j + 1))
            child3 = QtGui.QStandardItem("row: {}, col: {}".format(i, j + 2))
        parent_item.appendRow([child1, child2, child3])
        model.appendRow(parent_item)
    return model


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self._tree_view = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self._tree_view.setModel(create_model(self))
        self._tree_view.expandAll()
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self._tree_view)

        self._tree_view.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_doubleClicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QModelIndex")
    def on_doubleClicked(self, ix):
        print(ix.data())

        gp = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
        lp = self._tree_view.viewport().mapFromGlobal(gp)
        ix_ = self._tree_view.indexAt(lp)
        if ix_.isValid():
            print(ix_.data())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**PySide Version:**

```py
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


def create_model(parent):
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent)
    for i in range(3):
        parent_item = QtGui.QStandardItem("Family {}".format(i))
        for j in range(3):
            child1 = QtGui.QStandardItem("Child {}".format(i * 3 + j))
            child2 = QtGui.QStandardItem("row: {}, col: {}".format(i, j + 1))
            child3 = QtGui.QStandardItem("row: {}, col: {}".format(i, j + 2))
        parent_item.appendRow([child1, child2, child3])
        model.appendRow(parent_item)
    return model


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self._tree_view = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self._tree_view.setModel(create_model(self))
        self._tree_view.expandAll()
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self._tree_view)

        self._tree_view.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_doubleClicked)

    @QtCore.Slot("QModelIndex")
    def on_doubleClicked(self, ix):
        print(ix.data())

        gp = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
        lp = self._tree_view.viewport().mapFromGlobal(gp)
        ix_ = self._tree_view.indexAt(lp)
        if ix_.isValid():
            print(ix_.data())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc, thank you for your reply! I overlooked a very important detail, the project uses pyside, and according to this [link](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QWidget.customContextMenuRequested) QWidget only has one signal _customContextMenuRequested_ which also explains why I get an attribute error when using doubleClicked. I think I'll have to use the doubleClick event

Comment: @E_A What you point out is partially correct, is partially correct because QTreeView is a QWidget but it is also a QAbstractItemView, and the latter if it has the [doubleClicked signal](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractItemView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.doubleClicked). I have updated my answer for PySide.

Comment: yes sorry, I had managed to modify the solution to make it work with PySide but in the process I had mixed up the tree view and the Widget that contains it so that the doubleClicked signal generated a mistake. It works! Thank you!

Comment: @E_A On the other hand, for the next questions use the appropriate tag, if you are using pyside then use the pyside tag, and if you use pyqt4 then use the pqqt4 tag